# Java 8 Stream - is throwing stream has already been operated upon or closed

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I would like to implement a pagination in stream api.

I used if statement to modify the stream, but I was surprise when I encountered

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: stream has already been operated upon or closed
```

Here is my code

```
@Override
public List<Foo> search(String[] names, Integer offset, Integer size) {

    final Stream<Foo> fooStream = findAllFoos().stream();

    if(offset!=null) {
        fooStream
                .skip(offset)
                .limit(size);
    }

    if(ArrayUtils.isNotEmpty(names)) {
        fooStream.filter(foo -> ArrayUtils.contains(names, foo.getName()));
    }

    final List<Foo> foos = fooStream.collect(Collectors.toList()); //this lines throws the exception, according to stacktrace
    return foos;
}
```

Here is my Foo.class

```
public class Foo {
    private String name;
    //..setters and getters
}
```

Here is sample call to that search method

```
fooService.search(fooNamesArray, 0, 1);
fooService.search(fooNamesArray, null, null);
```

Comment: Aren't you supposed to assign to result of `limit` and `filter` to something (and make subsequent calls on that)?

Comment: Using nulls for boxed primitives is not recommended.

Answer (score 3):

```
fooStream.skip(offset)
```

does *nothing* by itself.  It returns a *new* `Stream`; it does not modify `fooStream`.

Generally speaking you can only use a `Stream` for one operation, though that might be a transformation into another `Stream`.

What you could do, though it would still make your code awkward, would be to write `fooStream = fooStream.skip(offset).limit(size)`.

Comment: It solved the exception but the stream no result is being returned. When I commented out either of if statement block it can returned a data.

if(offset!=null) {
            countryCodeStream = countryCodeStream
                    .skip(0)
                    .limit(2);
        }

        if(ArrayUtils.isNotEmpty(codes)) {
            countryCodeStream = countryCodeStream.filter(countryCode -> ArrayUtils.contains(codes, countryCode.getCode()));
        }

Comment: Okay, I solved it, the filter must comes first before the skip and limit.. which is odd.

Comment: @richersoon If you limit the stream to two elements, and neither of those first two elements match the predicate, then you have an empty stream.  If you want to find the first two elements that match the predicate, you need to first get the elements matching the predicate and then limit it to the first two.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to add all your validation before hand and combine all stream operations in one go.

```
List<Foo> foos = fooStream.skip(offset)
            .limit(size)
            .filter(foo -> ArrayUtils.contains(names, foo.getName()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

In other case, you can take the result of each stream operation into another stream and operate on them.

```
        Stream<Foo> skippedFooStream = Collections.<Foo>emptyList().stream();
    if(offset!=null) {
        skippedFooStream = fooStream
                .skip(offset)
                .limit(size);
    }

    if(ArrayUtils.isNotEmpty(names)) {
        // take this into another temp stream and proceed
        skippedFooStream.filter(foo -> ArrayUtils.contains(names, foo.getName()));
    }
```